# Multiple classnames - how to find only the next immediate one?

Tags: jquery

I have 3 expand divs with the same strcuture. Something like:

```
<div class="expand">
    <h3 class="more">Click to expand</h3>
    <div class="wrapper">Iasdfgh qwerty zxcvbn</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var toggleButton = $('.expand h3.more');
    var expandWrap = $(toggleButton).next('.wrapper');
    $(toggleButton).click(function(){
        if ($(expandWrap).is('.closed')) {
            $(toggleButton).removeClass('closed');
            $(expandWrap)
                .removeClass('closed')
                .slideDown('slow');

        } else {
            $(expandWrap)
                $(expandWrap).slideUp('slow', function(){
                    $(this).addClass('closed');
                    $(toggleButton).addClass('closed');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Right now when I click on the "Click to expand" `h3`, all `.wrapper` slides up and down. How can I only target the next immediate `.wrapper` so only one toggles at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var toggleButton = $('.expand h3.more');

    $(toggleButton).click(function(){
        var thisToggleButton = this;
        var expandWrap = $(thisToggleButton ).next('.wrapper');
        if (expandWrap.is('.closed')) {
            $(thisToggleButton ).removeClass('closed');
            expandWrap
                .removeClass('closed')
                .slideDown('slow');

        } else {
           expandWrap.slideUp('slow', function(){
                    $(this).addClass('closed');
                    $(thisToggleButton).addClass('closed');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use function next() :

http://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this quite a bit:

```
$(function(){
    $('.expand h3.more').on('click',function(){
        $(this).next('div.wrapper').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QzHYX/

**EDIT:** Note that if you are using an older version of jQuery, you'll have to change `on` to `live` for this to work.